# Exposing appengine cloud endpoints api on custom domain url address

Tags: java, rest, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have set of apis written on google appengine using google cloud endpoints. I want to publish these api's for other developers to consume by releasing the documentation generated through api-explorer. For this I would want my apis to be exposed on url such as `https://api.example.com/v1/` but all my api endpoints generated through appengine have a url signature as `https://module-dot-project-name.appspot.com/_ah/api/v1/`. I have tried mapping my api.example.com to the module serving the api's using the dispatch file, but I could not get my apis to work on my own domain address.

1) How can I get my apis to work on my own domain name?

2) How can I publish my api documentation using api-explorer serving on my own domain address? On url such as `https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=https://api.example.com#p/`

Answer (score 1):

1) is now possible with the newer version of cloud endpoints, called Cloud Endpoints Framework. [Here is the documentantion](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/serving-apis-from-domains), but if you are using the App Engine Standard environment it just works.

2) I'm not sure is possible. I only wrote this answer to addres number 1. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't.  From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/):

> **Note**: Google Cloud Endpoints does not support custom domains.