# Custom domain name for app engine cloud endpoints

Tags: java, rest, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

We have bought new domain from google and i have added the same to app-engine as custom domain. Unfortunately i am not able to access cloud endpoints from my custom domain.

According this question, it is NO
[No-Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36449534/exposing-appengine-cloud-endpoints-api-on-custom-domain-url-address)

But according to this link it is Yes
[Yes-Answer](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9384)

If you have done already, please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [migration details](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/migrating) for the recently released v2 of cloud endpoints

> The new framework brings a number of benefits, including:
>
> - Reduced request latency
> - Better integration with App Engine features (such as custom domains)

v1 didn't support custom domains. From the [issue tracker link](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9384) you posted:

> As long as you migrate to the new versions, it should work out of the box

Comment: i have followed this https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-java but it is not working as expected.